# Skip and limit after grouping don't work in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Skip and limit after grouping don't work in MongoDB Query.

I have 100 projects I want to group by status then add pagination on it. I want to get 10 projects per request. When I run my query it returns me all the projects with provided name.

This is my example

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "name": "MyProject"    }
}, {"$group": {"_id": { "status" : { "$ifNull" : ["$data.status", null]}}, "records": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}}}, {"$skip": 0}, {"$limit": 10}]);
```

This returns all the projects.

How can I solve this problem?  I can't do limit after grouping and if I do limit before the grouping operation, it does the limit but the grouping isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$setWindowFields` to compute in group rank and perform filtering using the index accordingly.

```js
db.projects.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": "MyProject"
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$status",
          null
        ]
      },
      "sortBy": {
        "createdDate": -1
      },
      "output": {
        "inGroupRank": {
          "$rank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      inGroupRank: {
        // pageSize: 5, pageIdx: 0
        $gt: 0,
        $lte: 5
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$status",
          null
        ]
      },
      records: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "records.inGroupRank"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5j3b0k0Lrzi)